# Memory leaks in .NET when doing async over sync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a situation where I *must* call an async method synchronously, and it is done so as follows:

```
 obj.asyncMethod().Wait(myCancelToken)
```

If the cancellation token is switched the disposable's within the task will not get disposed despite being activated via a *using* statement.

The below program illustrates the problem:

```
        using System;
        using System.Threading;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace LeakTest {

            class Program {
                static void Main(string[] args) {
                    try {
                        var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                        LongRunningTask().Wait(timeout.Token);
                    } catch (OperationCanceledException error) {                
                        //  handling timeout is logically okay, but expect nothing to be leaked
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Leaked Instances = {0}", DisposableResource.Instances);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                static async Task LongRunningTask() {
                    using (var resource = new DisposableResource()) {
                        await Task.Run( () => Thread.Sleep(1000));
                    }
                }

                public class DisposableResource : IDisposable {
                    public static int Instances = 0;
                    public DisposableResource() {
                        Instances++;
                    }

                    public void Dispose() {
                        Instances--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It seems Wait method just kills the task thread on cancellation instead of triggering an exception within that thread and letting it terminate naturally. Question is why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems Wait method just kills the task thread on cancellation instead of triggering an exception within that thread

You are incorrect, on when you cancel the only thing that happens is you stop waiting for `Wait(myCancelToken)` to complete, the task is still running in the background.

In order to cancel the background task you must pass the cancelation token into all of the methods down the chain. If you want the innermost layer (the long running one) to stop early that code must call [`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) throughout its code.

Comment: Okay, i see that only the Wait is cancelled. The issue for me is the outer scope *depends* on all inner scopes being fully disposed before it can be disposed. This obviously doesn't happen if the outer scope awaits a task subsequently cancelled (i.e. await resumes but task still running by itself).

Answer (score 5):

You've cancelled the task returned by `Wait(timeout.Token)` not the one returned from `LongRunningTask`, if you want to cancel that one pass the token to `Task.Run` and also use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` and pass the token there as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        LongRunningTask(timeout.Token).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException error)
    {
        //  handling timeout is logically okay, but expect nothing to be leaked
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Leaked Instances = {0}", DisposableResource.Instances);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task LongRunningTask(CancellationToken token)
{

    using (var resource = new DisposableResource())
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000, token), token);
    }
}

public class DisposableResource : IDisposable
{
    public static int Instances = 0;
    public DisposableResource()
    {
        Instances++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Instances--;
    }
}
```

**Note** that the using statment will still dispose of the resource once the long running operation finishes. Run this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try {
            var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            LongRunningTask().Wait(timeout.Token);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException error) {                
            //  handling timeout is logically okay, but expect nothing to be leaked
        }

    Console.WriteLine("Leaked Instances = {0}", DisposableResource.Instances);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task LongRunningTask()
{
    using (var resource = new DisposableResource())
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    }
}

public class DisposableResource : IDisposable
{
    public static int Instances = 0;
    public DisposableResource()
    {
        Instances++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Instances--;
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed resource. Leaked Instances = {0}", Instances);
    }
}
```

**Output**
Leaked Instances = 1
Disposed resource. Leaked Instances = 0

Comment: In my case the Thread.Sleep is actually a database.BulkInsert call which has no cancellation token support. The issue for me is that the outer scope depends on everything in the inner scope being disposed, which does not happen because as you point out -- it's still running in the background.

Comment: yes, and once it finishes it will be disposed. See my update answer for an example.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Yes but if outer scope connection is disposed before inner scope command, the outer scope dispose will throw.